# How to Retrieve Lines of Code Changed in a Bitbucket Pull Request using atlassian-python-api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, bitbucket, atlassian-python-api

I'm working on a project and using the `atlassian-python-api` to interact with Bitbucket. I'm trying to retrieve the lines of code changed in a pull request, but I'm unable to find a specific function in the atlassian library that directly provides this information.

I have successfully fetched the pull requests using the `get_pull_requests()` function, but it doesn't include the lines of code changed (loc_changed). I understand that I might need to retrieve the diff information for each pull request to calculate this.

However, upon checking the available functions in the atlassian library, I couldn't find a direct method to fetch the diff for a pull request.

Could someone guide me on how to retrieve the lines of code changed in a Bitbucket pull request using the `atlassian-python-api` or suggest an alternative approach within the library to obtain this information?

I was expecting to find a method within the atlassian library that directly retrieves the diff or changes for a specific pull request. I aimed to use this information to calculate the lines of code changed (additions and deletions) and update the loc_changed field in a custom PullRequest object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to use this with Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or a self-hosted Bitbucket? (They have the same name but they do not share any code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `diffstat` method on the pull request object

```
bitbucket = Cloud(...)
workspace = bitbucket.workspaces.get("workspace")
repository = workspace.repositories.get("id")
prs = repository.pullrequests.each()

for pr in prs:
    loc_changed = sum([stat.lines_added + stat.lines_removed for stat in pr.diffstat()])
```